# How to add hibernate filter in Grails 4

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I want to add global hibernate filter for a specific domain to keep my queries as clean as possible.

In previous projects I used the [grails-hibernate-filter](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/goodstartgenetics/grails-hibernate-filter) plugin which is not working/available for the latest GORM version.

How could I manually add hibernate fiter to a specific domain class?

I wasn't able to find a documentation for that.

***Additions based on comments:***

The current application already uses discriminator based multi-tenancy to support multiple tenants. Now I need further distinctions for each tenant.

Taking this example domain:

```
class Vehicle implements MultiTenant<Vehicle> { 
    String manufacturer
    String color

    static mapping = {
        tenantId name:'manufacturer'  
    }
}
```

Currently a user just gets all vehicles for its tenant.
Now I want to provide a way that the user will just get vehicles for its tenant and a specific color. I don't want to add a color condition for each query. Instead I want to add a hibernate filter to `Vehicle`. Using the hibernate plugin I would be able to do something like:

```
static hibernateFilters = {
    colorFilter(condition: 'color = :color', types: 'string')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of try adding hibernate filter manually, I found a [fork](https://github.com/yvdlima/grails-hibernate-filter) of the grails-hibernate-filter plugin which is working with Grails 4.

Seems to work as intended. At least for my current requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation during my upgrade. I evaluated the option of bringing the grails-hibernate-filter plugin to life using various patches, but that felt like a dead end.

Since I mainly used the plugin for multi-tenancy, Grails built-in support for multi-tenancy provided a good replacement after a few roundabouts.

If your use-case is different (more complicated than an added tenant id), you might want to look into DRY reuse of queries in Grails 3+. I did some research in that direction, before I decided on pure multi-tenancy.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I already use discriminator based multi-tenancy and need further hibernate filter for my use case. Hope for more hints on how to add hibernate filter before switching to another approach. :-)

Comment: Could you include code that addresses "How could I manually add hibernate fiter to a specific domain class?"?

Comment: No, my answer is "you can't", and then suggests alternative approaches. Too vague and better to delete it?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I updated my question to hopefully make it more understandable. :-)

Comment: "Too vague and better to delete it?" - I don't think it is too vague and I don't think you should delete it.  It may be the best answer.  I didn't realize that we didn't have support for that.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown There is really no way to add a hibernate filter using GORM?

Comment: "There is really no way to add a hibernate filter using GORM?" - You (@aiolos) said that it isn't supported to manually add a hibernate filter to a specific domain class.  That is what I said that I didn't know that we didn't have support for.  I did not intend to say that there is really no way to add a hibernate filter using GORM.  There is.